# Converting to string

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I'm loading this bundle that handles translations.

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.ni.lib.extra.delivery.ExtraBundle" var="extra" />
```

It is used as a regular bean. So, if I need the value of the "welcome" key, then I do it like this

```
#{extra.welcome}.
```

The problem is that I have to transform whatever is returned by this extra variable into a string for javascript use. Right now, this is what happens

```
var hello = #{extra.Hello};
```

In the browser, this is what shows up

```
var hello = Hello;
```

and causes an error because the variable Hello is not defined. How can I transform that into "Hello"?

Comment: what error are you talking about

Comment: Hello is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
var hello = #{extra.Hello};
```

By

```
var hello = "#{extra.Hello}";
```

This way, Hello will be recognized as a string, an not as a var.